# Passing value from zend form to another action

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element, getparameter, get-request

i am using zend framework and i'm still confuse about passing value from zend_form to another action.
let's say we have a guestbook, you fill your $name and $message in it, then after we click submit, the success page will say "thank you $name" ..

I manage to pass the parameter but, when i echoing it, it only display the first letter. if i'm insert the name = Frank, then the success page says "thank you F " .....

do have any suggestion or answer related to my problem. thanks .

Comment: How are you retrieving and passing the code? Are you using $_GET['name']?

Comment: my form using post method , inserting to database, then forwarding it to success page using _forward().. 
in the successAction, i am using getParam to get the parameter from the form, something like this : $gb_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('guestbook_id');...  .
 and in View, i call the parameter with $this->list['guestbook_name']; . i just don't understand why zend only view the first letter. perhaps there is somethink wrong with my  $this->view->list in successAction..

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the [Flash Messenger](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.flashmessenger.basicusage)

You'd use it to pass information to the next page by storing it in the session until the next request.